# How to create a map in JavaScript in VisualForce page

Tags: javascript-remoting

I am trying to create a map in VisualForce page where I also need to pass the inputtext value dynamically. Also once the calling the apex method defined as @RemoteAction will return back SObject[ ] so I need to retrieve it in JavaScript and then need to use this in my pageblock table value in VF page. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

Code:

```
global with sharing class MainClass{

@RemoteAction

  global static SObject[] findMethod(map<string,string> request){

  /*Purpose: this function will be called from the UI,

    request contains the string key-value pairs

    @return: the function would return list of sobject

  */

        //my logic

    return sObject;

  }
```

JAVASCRIPT written in VF page:

```
function findFunc() { 

  //var apexInput = document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:someId').value;

  var searchStr=document.getElementById("{!$Component.form1.pb1.pbs1.inptText1}").value;

  var request = {

                 'find': searchStr,

                 'sobject': 'abc__c',

                 'fields': 'Name,Id,Status__c',

                 'where': 'Name like \'%'+searchStr+'%\' OR Id like \'%'+searchStr+'%\' OR Status__c=:'+searchStr+''};

  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(

                    '{!$RemoteAction.MainClass.findMethod}',

                    request,

                    function(result, event) { },   // What i need to do here ?     

                );               

}
```

VF page line where I need to pass the value:

```
<apex: pageblock le value="{!SObjectArray}" var="a">
```

Here sObjectArray return by my RemoteAction method.

Comment: I think there are easier ways to do this without writing your own JS... You want to change the records displayed in the table based on user input right? Try: 1. Binding the table value to a list of sObjects in the controller 2. Binding your user inputs to values on the controller 3. Writing a function that populates the list using a query composed of your input values 4. Calling that function from a command button on your VF page that rerenders your pageBlockTable

Comment: Hi Chaie123, Thanks for your reply. But actually we already have a util remote action method which we would like to reuse. So that method will be taking parameters as sosl query and will return the sObject[ ] so I need to use that sObject[ ] into my pageblock table. Could you please help me with that.